# How can I update an integer column with a value from a decimal column in two tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [Kana]         NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Kanji]        NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [FrequencyA]   INT              NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PhrasePhraseChapter] FOREIGN KEY ([ChapterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PhraseChapter] ([PhraseChapterShortId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FreqLeeds] (
    [Id]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [Freq] DECIMAL (18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

How can I update the `FrequencyA` column of the `Phrase` table with the integer value of `Freq` column in the `FreqLeeds` table if the value in the Kanji column matches that of the Text column in FreqLeeds? Note that I am not bothered about the numbers after the decimal 
point in the `FreqLeeds` table.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the error or the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query helps you to update the Phrase table.

```
UPDATE p
SET FrequencyA = CAST(fl.Freq as INT)
FROM dbo.Phrase p
JOIN dbo.FreqLeeds fl
ON fl.[Text] = p.Kanji
```

I would like to highlight that if the Decimal value in the Freq is greater than the range of the Integer data type, you will run into errors.

Avoid having different data types in different tables, when they are related to each other.